# GetSlotFromBufferLocked error occurred

Tags: android, android-studio

The error getslotfrombufferlocked has occurred during the running of the app using Marshmallow 6.0. And I want to run my app on Marshmallow 6.0.Please guide me the way.

The build.gradle file is given below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
         useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.project.myproject"
            minSdkVersion 8
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions{
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    }
```

The error is:

```
07-17 20:02:42.490 1457-4496/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fa11a5b20
07-17 20:02:45.282 21549-21586/com.project.myproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f8cc5a1a0
07-17 20:02:46.995 21549-21586/com.project.myproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f8cc5a240
07-17 20:02:54.920 21549-21586/com.project.myproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f8cc56d20
07-17 20:03:01.793 1457-4496/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f8796a780
```

Comment: Please add the code for your main activity so we can examine and suggest possible solutions. Also, please confirm that your device is running `Android 6.0.1` or later.

Comment: I have the Android 6.0 and not 6.0.1, so how can I rectify this problem? My main activity is given below :

Comment: Thanks for the updates - by the way, you should have added it to your question instead of posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My login activity is given below:

```
package com.project.myproject;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class loginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button login,forg,use;
    EditText uid ,pass ;
    TextView tv ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        forg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.forg);
        use=(Button)findViewById(R.id.use);
        uid=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
        pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String u = uid.getText().toString();
               String p = pass.getText().toString();
                if(u.isEmpty()|| p.isEmpty())
                {
            tv.setText("PROVIDE VALUE");
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tv.setTextSize(30);
                }
                else {
                    Intent i2=getIntent();
                    String type=i2.getStringExtra("type");
                    if (u.equals(p) && (type != "Faculty")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(loginActivity.this, studentLoginActivity.class);
                        //i.putExtra("uid",u);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else if(u.equals(p) && (type != "Student")) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(loginActivity.this, facultyLoginActivity.class);
                        //i.putExtra("uid",u);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                     else {
                        tv.setText("Login Failed");
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        tv.setTextSize(30);
                    }
                }
                }
    });
    forg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i1=new Intent(loginActivity.this,forgetPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
    use.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i2=new Intent(loginActivity.this,newUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

When I go from login activity to new user activity then the getslotfrombufferlocked occurred and my new user activity code is given below:

```
    package com.project.myproject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class newUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText uid, pass, ans, con;
    Spinner sp1, sp2;
    public String[] type = {"Select type", "Faculty", "Student"};
    //String passw,cpass,answ,spin1,spin2;
    //int id1;
    private static String url_insertion = "http://localhost/insertion.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    Button reg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);
        Intent i2 = getIntent();
        Intent i5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginActivity.class);
        i5.putExtra("type", type);
        //startActivity(i5);
        uid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        ans = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        con = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.con);
        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        Button reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);

        String[] quest = {"Select Question", "What is your pet's name", "What is your favorite color", "What is the place do you like most", "Which is your favorite book"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, quest);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(newUserActivity.this, "You Have Selected" + sp1.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, type);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(newUserActivity.this, "You Have Selected" + sp2.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int ID = Integer.parseInt(uid.getText().toString());
                String Password = pass.getText().toString();
                String Question = sp1.getAdapter().toString();
                String Answer = ans.getText().toString();
                String Type = sp2.getAdapter().toString();
                new BackgroundTask().execute(ID,Password,Question,Answer,Type);
            }
        });
    }
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(newUserActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args){
            String ID = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            String Password = args[1];
            String Question = args[2];
            String Answer = args[3];
            String Type = args[4];
            List<NameValuePair>params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID",ID));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",Password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Question",Question));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Answer",Answer));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type",Type));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insertion,"POST",params);
            Log.d("Create Response",json.toString());
            try{
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(success==1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),loginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        public void execute(int id, String password, String question, String answer, String type) {
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly give me answer to resolve it.

Comment: Can you please comment out the code in the `doInBackground` where you are starting the activity - comment the line  `startActivity(i);` and the line below it: ` finish();` - and then try to run the app again. Let me know what happens then. I am suspecting this might be causing the issue.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla during the execution of my app I again found same error ,i.e. , getslotfrombufferlocked

Comment: Even after making the changes as I suggested? Could you please paste the whole error log? Perhaps there are indications as to which line causes this - but I do suspect it might have something to do with the code you have in the `doInBackground` - so perhaps commenting most that code out (especially the `try-catch` block) and see what if the error goes away.